# reywood:bootstrap3-sass throws error : meteor 1.0

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have a Meteor 1.0 app that is happily running with `mizzao:bootstrap-3`. But... I'd prefer to semantically name my styles using Sass, and was hoping to use `reywood:bootstrap3-sass`. However, removing `mizzao:bootstrap-3` and adding `reywood:bootstrap3-sass` causes a startup error:

ETA: The complete stack trace is as follows:

```
$ meteor

[[[[[ ~/meteor/supercharger ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:384:34
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:87:22)
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:377:7
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at compileUnibuild (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:376:5)
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:1077:27
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at Object.compiler.compile (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:1076:5)
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2004:26
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:250:13
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:243:29
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:241:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:232:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at Object.capture (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:231:19)
  at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1926:31)
  at bundleApp (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:509:28)
  at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:527:24)
  at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:744:28)
  at /Users/path_to/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.19eyvkb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:380:12
```

I had this problem with the `reywood:font-awesome` package as well. Is this a know issue or is there more information I can provide? The package list is:

```
$ meteor list
accounts-password            1.0.4  Password support for accounts
coffeescript                 1.0.4  Javascript dialect with fewer braces and semicolons
http                         1.0.8  Make HTTP calls to remote servers
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  1.1.20  Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui with multi-language support.
iron:router                  1.0.1  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform              1.2.0  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
natestrauser:font-awesome    4.2.0  Latest version Font-Awesome loaded via CDN
particle4dev:sass            1.0.0  SASS for meteor
percolatestudio:synced-cron  1.0.0  Allows you to define and run scheduled jobs across multiple servers.
reywood:bootstrap3-sass      3.3.0_1  Bootstrap 3 with Sass support
sacha:spin                   2.0.4  Simple spinner package for Meteor
```

Comment: :I tried adding both the packages in my newly created meteor 1.0 app. It is working perfectly fine. Can you be more specific?A complete error log would be helpful.

Comment: Added complete stack trace.